# Floor effects in Bayesian estimate, can I reparameterize?

Tags: bayesian, parameterization

I'm replicating an old study and I have two sets of existing estimates which measure a similar effect, namely the presence of a studied item in memory over time:

```
a <-c( .42, .31, .26, .11, .02, .001, .001, .001, .1 )
b <-c( .17, .14, .03, .025, .06, .08, .06, .06, .08)
```

Both series of estimates are based on very similar data but the estimates seem to deviate very strongly from each other after an initial stage of similarity. The original authors attribute this to floor effects and processing related differences. I would like to estimate those effects in my model since they seem to cause a lot of trouble there.

In my model (Bayesian inference), a and b are estimated using a regression like structure, e.g.:

$$
a \sim dnorm(\mu_a, \tau_a)\\
\mu_a \leftarrow \lambda_a t^{-\beta}\\
\tau_a \sim dgamma(0.1,0.001)\\
\beta \sim dbeta(0,4)\\
\lambda_a \sim dunif(0,1)\\
$$

Where $t$ is the time. As a result of the strange effects in the above estimates, the $\beta$ estimate suffers and the resulting curves do not fit the data as much as I would expect them to. Is it possible to relieve this issue by adding a parameter that encodes the floor effect:

$$
\mu_a \leftarrow \lambda_a t^{-\beta} + f\\
f \sim dbeta(0,1)
$$

Where $f$ is the floor-effect parameter. Would it make sense to add this parameter only to those conditions where the floor effect occurs? Or would it be better practice to add it to all conditions?